# Regex for mobile phone

Tags: java, regex, validation, jsf

I would like to validate some JSF's fields using Validators. I am searching for a pattern to validate a mobile phone number which accept only these conditions:

1- can contain an optional '+' at the beginning (and there should be no space just after the '+' from the beginning).

2- The number may then contain one to several characters from:

- numeric characters [0-9]
- hyphen (-)
- space
- point (.)

I am using this pattern `(^\\+)?[0-9\\s-\\.]*` but it doesn't work and specially I can't realise this condition "there should be no space just after the '+' from the beginning"

**My code:**

```
public Boolean isValid(String str) throws PatternSyntaxException {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\+)?[0-9\\s-\\.]*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(telFax);
        boolean result = matcher.matches();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets read your question piece by piece :

Can contain an optional '+' at the beginning (and there should be no space just after the '+' from the beginning).

```
^\+?\S
```

The number may then contain one to several characters from:

- numeric characters [0-9]
- hyphen (-)
- space
- point (.)

---

Your final regex should look like :

```
^\+?[0-9-\.][0-9\s-\.]*
```

---

[**Check the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Iwmg61/1)

---

Your Java code can look like this :

```
public Boolean isValid(String telFax) {
    String regex = "^\\+?[0-9-\\.][0-9\\s-\\.]*";
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(telFax).matches();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The answer of YCF_L is perfect, I just wanted to add that according to the description of the validator in the question (especially point number 2), nothing prevents a phone number from beginning with a space.

So the regex should be :

```
^(\+[0-9-\.])?[0-9\s-\.]*
```